# AngularJS how to apply js changes for the ng-routed files without controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular js, i have to apply javascript changes for the ng-routed pages, how to do that without controller.
**Index.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="/routing/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/routing/services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/routing/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>


<section ng-view="" class="top-page">
</section>

<script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/app.js"></script>
<script src="script/controller.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#home").html("Home page");
</script>
```

**home.html**

```
<h1 id="home"></h1>
```

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module("LearnRouting", ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider.html5
            $routeProvider
            .when("/",{
                templateUrl:"pages/home.html",
                controller:"homeController"
            })
            .when("/about",{
                templateUrl:"pages/about.html",
                controller:"homeController"
            })
            .when("/contact",{
                templateUrl:"pages/contact.html",
                controller:"homeController"
            })
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });
```

This is my code. the home.html loads javascript is not affecting its id value in it respective page. I need when the home.html loads, the home id should be affected. how to do that?. with this help only i need to handle related project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got answer by googling. We cannot load a index script file for the routed files. So i have did like the below:
**script.js**

```
$("#home").html("Home page");
```

And added script.js to the home.html

**home.html**

```
<h1 id="home"></h1>
<script src="script/script.js"></script>
```

It worked for me. If any other suggestions, kindly answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your jquery is running before the page loads and before the router is hooked up. You should move the jquery code to a `$(document).ready` block, and also move it to the html page you want it to be executed in. Don't leave it on your root page if it should only be used on a sub page.

Comment: Thanks for your response!But i have some js plugin files for animation in order to apply for the whole page. Now how should i do for that.